# How to execute a query in the background with Apollo?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, apollo, react-apollo

We're adding Apollo to an existing mobile app built with React-Native.

Today we use Redux-Saga to dispatch actions and execute background requests, sometimes with a certain delay for technical reasons. We want to do the same thing with the Apollo client.

Given the mechanism of Apollo client, executing a refetch on a `useQuery` from a screen with a setTimeout to add a 5-10 seconds delay could potentially break, whenever the component gets unmounted. Though, we still want that refetch to get executed, but later, even if I'm on a completely different screen.

At the moment I'm getting the following error when I try a refetch on an unmounted screen:

> TypeError - undefined is not an object (evaluating 'c.currentObservable.query.refetch')

I'm looking for a solution to refetch data in the background with a delay. Once the fetch is successful it would update all the components using that same query.

Almost like adding instructions to a queue that needs to be executed later.

I'm thinking to use a global context to execute those, but I'm not sure that's the right solution and I'm wondering if anyone has this kind of use case and how they've resolved them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With react, if you try to execute anything on unmounted component it will always though you error. This is component behaviour and is not specific to apollo client.

It doesn't seems to be right approach to execute refetch after 10 sec as the component can go in unmount state within 10 sec because of user action.

You can use apollo client to execute query outside component, similar to how axios is used and can be even used with redux-saga.

```js
apolloClient
  .query({
     query: QUERY,
     fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
  })
  .then (res => {})
  .catch(err => {})
```